# Random Index Error

Tags: python, client, client-server

Hi thank you for checking out my question.
I am using Python 2.7 on windows 7. I have a while-loop in my code to keep polling data. The output from first circle is right, but crashed from next. The result is shown below.
[image]

The code (while loop part) is shown in below.
[image]

What the code does is (client) sending a command (getdigitalsensors) to server from Line 114, receiving the result (from Line 116), parsing it (from Line 121) and printing out.

From the result (first screenshot), the result (Bumper bits are:) from second loop got something wrong, but I cannot figure out why...any help will appreciate~

Comment: Please put the information into your question as text. Images are helpful for backup, but your question shouldn't depend on them.

Comment: Have you tried printing the data variable.  IndexError means that your expecting an array of at least length.  Its not receiving the data your expecting.  So you want to see what you actually receiving to see if that helps you debug the issue... you have a time delay of one second.. also try increasing that value. Or add a while loop that waits for the data to have a length of at least 12 before trying the access the data.